# parse a string date in particular format, fail otherwise

Tags: sql-server, date, parsing, datetime

Yes, I know that the following is not best practice, but inherited db.

I have string as 'MM/dd/yy tt:hh:mm'. At times string is 'tt:hh:mm' in error.

If I cast 'tt:hh:mm' to datetime, it succeeds, and puts in default date as 1900-01-01. I would want this to fail.

isdate(' 08:00:00') success returns 1.

I would want the following:

```
myisdatetime(' 08:00:00') fails return 0
myisdatetime( 'MM/dd/yy tt:hh:mm') success returns 1
```

Maybe even specify datetime format. i.e. Parse exact.

Comment: Maybe just cast to datetime, and then check the string to see if it contains the substring `1900-01-01` and fail based on that? Is that date ever a valid entry? @SeanLange also has a very good point

Comment: Maybe as simple as checking charindex of '/'??

Comment: Surely, that can't be the right format?  Do you mean to say `MM/dd/yy tt:hh:mm`? (you have `mm` [the minutes] specified twice, once for the month, and once for the minutes).

Comment: `At times string is 'tt:hh:mm' in error.` - you say this, but your example shows a test case of `08:00:00`.  That's not the format you specified...  `tt:hh:mm` = `PM:04:17`, which is an extremely odd way of denoting the time, but does not match your question.

Comment: What is tt in this format? Shouldn't it be hh:mm:ss?

Comment: Please familiarize yourself with the [**proper `DateTime` component abbreviations**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) and revise your question.  It's the crux of your question, and as written, it's extremely vague and misleading.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQGAr.png

Answer (score 0):

**Just simply use CONVERT**

```
DECLARE @InputTime VARCHAR(20) = ' 08:00:00';
SELECT TRY_CONVERT(TIME, @InputTime, 114);
SELECT CONVERT(TIME, @InputTime, 114);
```

**You should now your input data - if you want to fail in case of space - just check it:**

```
DECLARE @Result BIT = 0;
SET @Result = CASE CHARINDEX(' ', @InputTime) WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END;
SELECT @Result;
```

**Similarly with DATETIME**

```
DECLARE @InputDT VARCHAR(20) = '23/10/17 08:00:00';
SELECT TRY_CONVERT(DATETIME, @InputDT, 3);
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, @InputDT, 3);
```

more: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql